# Executing "ng serve" or "npm start" command browser is not opening automatically

Tags: angular, npm

I have generated a project using angular-cli by following steps given in installation section. Project is running right now. But i have to open browser manually by typing http://localhost:4200/ into browser.

Could it be possible like when user will execute "ng serve" or "npm start" command, browser will open automatically?

Please let me know if it is possible or give me any solution for this.

Comment: In angular/cli using the --open (or just -o) option will automatically open your browser on http://localhost:4200/.For Example `ng serve --open`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://angular.io/cli/serve#options) you can use a flag with `ng serve`:

> `--open` (`-o`) Opens the url in default browser.

You may need update your version for this functionality, as the revision history of the wiki page suggests it's a recent addition.

Comment: @ChanakaJ while you're at it check what `ng -v` tells you

Comment: _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.4
node: 6.10.0
os: win32 x64

Comment: @ChanakaJ ascii art aside, that seems new enough to support the flag. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

One developer of theangular-cli team said on  Jun 17, 2016;

> We don't have this functionality at the moment, no. But I'll leave the
>   issue open as a 'nice to have'.

but

You could just change what npm start does in the package.json.

E.g. change

```
"start": "ng serve"
```

to

```
"start": "start http://localhost:4201 & ng serve -port 4201"
```

Comment: No in some projects npm start open browser automatically

Comment: Could you link to where they said that? It seems from a comment above that it's no longer true.

Comment: Now You need ============= npm start ============  to run app, not ng serve . Just saying

Answer (score 0):

You need to  update below code under  package.json
"start": "ng serve --port 4214 -o",

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32160530)